# Invalid syntax when working with a Python graph and dictionary problem

Tags: python, dictionary, graph

This is the problem I am working on: https://leetcode.com/problems/find-the-town-judge/

My code is below. I am getting an Invalid Syntax error for

```
            truster[truster_key] = 0:
```

However the error message is not detailed so all it says is invalid syntax. I am not sure why it's invalid, all I'm doing is adding to my Python dictionary.

```
class Solution(object):
    def findJudge(self, N, trust):
        """
        :type N: int
        :type trust: List[List[int]]
        :rtype: int
        """
        if len(trust) == 0:
            return N

    count = 0

    trusted = {}
    truster = {}

    for i in range(len(trust)):
        trusted_key = trust[i][1]
        if trust[i][1] not in trusted:
            trusted[trusted_key] = 0
        else:
            trusted[trusted_key] = trusted[trusted_key] + 1

    for i in range(len(trust)):
        truster_key = truster[i][0]
        if trust[i][0] not in truster:
            truster[truster_key] = 0:
        else:
            truster[truster_key] == truster[truster_key] + 1

    for i in trusted:
        if i not in truster and trusted[i] >= N - 1:
            return i
    return -1
```

Comment: `truster[truster_key] = 0:` What is that colon doing on the end?

Comment: Also, `truster[truster_key] == truster[truster_key] + 1` does nothing. `==` is an _equality test_, not an _assignment_.